# Configuring Elasticsearch with docker install

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog2

The only mention of configuring ES in the docker page is that one can pass in an ES_MEMORY field
http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.1/pages/installation/docker.html

I've started a docker Graylog2, and am getting the 'Elasticsearch nodes with too low open file limit' message. I can see there is a page for configuring ES:
http://docs.graylog.org/en/1.1/pages/configuring_es.html

But I'm not sure where elasticsearch.yml or graylog.conf is stored. Docker seems to be a black box. But maybe I'm misunderstanding docker. Must I 'go into' the container somehow, to find these files?

Is the docker install a viable production option? "We strongly recommend to use a dedicated Elasticsearch cluster for your Graylog setup." - (I'm using the one that comes with the docker file, so I presume I'm ok?).